# PHP - multi-dimensional array overwriting first value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a multi-dimensional array to match the hierarchy of a company. I ask the database for the downline (saved in a seperate table) and start looping it. **Currently I'm only doing this for the highest level and the people below him**. I know he has 6 people below him, thus the end result only shows one. When I var_dump $complete every time in the loop, I see different values in the children-array. (AKA he overwrites instead of adds up).

I've tried both array_push and this method, I hope I've been clear enough, because I probably don't (sorry.)

The code:

```
foreach ($downpositions as $downposition) {    
        // start position
        if ($downposition['PositionsDownposition']['positionsdownpositions_rel_position'] == 1) {
            // check downline only on first level
            if ($downposition['PositionsDownposition']['positionsdownpositions_level'] == 1) {

                foreach ($downpositions as $mother) {

                    if ($mother['PositionsDownposition']['positionsdownpositions_rel_downposition'] == 1) {

                        // format it
                        $node = array(
                            'id' => $downposition['PositionsDownposition']['positionsdownpositions_id'],
                            'name' => $downposition['PositionsDownposition']['positionsdownpositions_rel_position'],
                            'children' => array()
                        );

                        $complete = array(
                            'id' => $mother['PositionsDownposition']['positionsdownpositions_id'],
                            'name' => $mother['PositionsDownposition']['positionsdownpositions_rel_position'],
                            'children' => array()
                        );

                        // add up to array
                        $complete['children'][] = $node;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, im intialising $complete['children'] in the loop, thus resetting the array to empty all the time.

Solution:
Re-do the code, initialise of $complete outside the loop.